# How to access SQLite database in Android Tablet?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need your help on SQLite database development, We have an application existing with 3rd party database which help us to store collected measurement data using Android Tablet.

For example : Time of recording, Latitude , Longitude.

These should be recorded in mobile and tablet devices.

I tried to get database schema through the DDMS file explorer but I do not see any .db file.
Usually these are stored under data/data.

Our intention is to create own SQLite database and this will support to store huge data.

In above scenario, how should I get 3rd party database schema ?

I have tried, but it doesn't gave me successful result with emulator and SQLite manager ?

In general how do i access db in real device?

Comment: the path is **/data/data/your.app.name/databases/**

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this as it's been a while, but you I don't think you can access data from another application. That is unless you have rooted the device.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supposed to store some huge data, you should set your database on a server and connect to it from your application on the android-device via internet.
For this you have to know How to connect to a SQLite database and config the server's firewall to have access to the database using your app.

Follow these links :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html